# Oauth2 springboot after successful validation credentials flow

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, microservices, two-factor-authentication

I am building login application using OAuth2 and spring boot microservice. The challenge I facing is implementing two factor authentiation. Once the user enters credentials when gets successful then before sending
access token to frontend it should call another microservice to send sms to phone number which is present in access token.
Currently I am using flag **IS_TFA_ENABLED=Y if Y** then making other ajax call to send sms to phone number received in access token,But i want this sms service to be called at server side only after credentials are validated successfullyand shoot another sms service call.
Any suggestion how to implement this ?
front end code is below

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8095/oauth2-service/oauth/token",
      data: "username="+username+"&password="+password+"&grant_type=password",
      beforeSend: function(request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+btoa("clientId:password"));
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
          },
      success: function(msg){   
            **if(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg)).is_tfa_enabled=="Y") {**
                
                **var email_two_fa_url = "http://localhost:8095/user-service/users/"+JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg)).id
                +"/emails/"+JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg)).userName+"/2fa";
                
                var mobile_two_fa_url = "http://localhost:8095/user-service/users/"+JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg)).id
                +"/mobilenumbers/"+JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg)).mobile+"/2fa";
                
                var verify_2fa_url = "http://localhost:8095/user-service/users/"+JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg)).id
                +"/codes/";**
            
                sessionStorage.setItem("email_two_fa_url",email_two_fa_url);
                sessionStorage.setItem("mobile_two_fa_url",mobile_two_fa_url);
                sessionStorage.setItem("verify_2fa_url",verify_2fa_url);
                
                sessionStorage.setItem("access_token", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg)).access_token);
                sessionStorage.setItem("refresh_token", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg)).refresh_token);
                    
               if(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg)).tfa_default_type=="SMS") {
                   two_fa_url = mobile_two_fa_url;
               } else {
                   two_fa_url = email_two_fa_url;
               }
                
                send2facode(two_fa_url, function() {
                    $("#myModal").modal('show');
                });
            }else{
                localStorage.setItem("access_token", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg)).access_token);
                localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg)).refresh_token);
                window.location.reload("permissions.html");
            }
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         $(".alert-danger").show();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose to develop two authentication services:

1. The first service provide authentication user login/password. If the
   credentials are corrects, it sends the SMS, saves the code in the
   database for verification and returns back a temporary token that
   contains only the user id and one authorization for the second service
   (SECOND_FACT_AUTH for example). It is possible to insert the code
   inside the to ken to avoid the access to database.
2. The second service secured by the authorization "SECOND_FACT_AUTH"
   that checks the code in database or inside the token according to
   where you store it, then it generates the traditional authentication and
   refresh tokens.